# Cheap second-hand bookstores/antiquaries in Tallinn

Tags: shopping, estonia, tallinn, baltic-region

I am looking for places to buy bilingual technical and specialist dictionaries of any sort while in Tallinn at a good price (preferably used ones).

Also I have little idea of the linguistic situation there, will I be able to communicate in English or Russian in such places?

Comment: Okay, so at least I don't have to go to a course of Estonian just yet – good to know, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I have seen [mention](https://www.inyourpocket.com/tallinn/shopping/bookshops):

> You won’t find a great selection of books in English or other foreign languages in Tallinn, but you won’t be left without any reading material either.

The same site offers only one mention of "antique books".
So without any personal experience of [Raamatukoi](https://www.raamatukoi.ee/cgi-bin/antikvariaat) I suggest it perhaps better than no answer at all. At least you can browse some of what is available there without visiting.

You should have no problems with language: 
    [it is not uncommon in Estonia to speak two or three foreign languages. English is understood and spoken by many of the residents](https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Travel-g274958-s409/Tallinn:Estonia:First.Time.Visitors.html) and in 2011 [(46.7%) spoke Russian as their native language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tallinn).

Comment: In some places "antique books" or "antikvariat" refers specifically to expensive old collector books, "rare books", and not also to generic used paperbacks etc. In other places all used books are lumped together and the shops are indeed called "antiquariat" or such. I'm about to visit a Raamatukoi for the first time. I'm expecting that they sell both.